# How can I convert this linq.expression from C# to VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, .net-4.0

```
[QueryInterceptor("Somethings")]
public Expression<Func<Something, bool>> OnSomethings()
{
    // Code here
}
```

I had a view guesses, looked on msdn, but there are no examples matching the way that that is used. Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<QueryInterceptor("Somethings")> _
Public Function OnSomethings() As Expression(Of Func(Of Something, Boolean))
    ' Code here
End Function
```

Comment: wahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh I can't believe I didn't put Function at the start! I tried everything else... Thanks!